# mysql workbench with mariadb

Tags: debian, mariadb, mysql-workbench

I have a clean installation of debian 9 64bits.

On it I used the mariadb repository for 10.2 and installed mariadb.

After that, I installed mysql-workbench from the debian repo, but when I try to open mysql-workbench I get thoses errors messages:

```
/usr/lib/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench-bin: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmariadbclient.so.18: version `libmariadbclient_18' not found (required by /usr/lib/libgdal.so.20)
/usr/lib/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench-bin: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmariadbclient.so.18: version `libmariadbclient_18' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlcppconn.so.7)
```

I do have the file /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmariadbclient.so.18 installed. I also tried to purge both mariadb and mysql-workbench and reinstalling them, but still have the exact same error message.

Comment: Note that MySQL Workbench is solely made for MySQL and only tested with MySQL servers.

Comment: @MikeLischke On older version of debian (debian 7 and 8) I had no problem connecting workbench with mariadb out of the box. Some features did not work, but what I needed was there. If only I could manage to make it run